# Ubuntu-16.04 PC + WiFi-dongle connects to WiFi-Router, but problem with Wired connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

My desktop PC running Ubuntu 16.04, with a TP-Link USB2.0 WiFi-dongle connects properly to my TP-Link MR3220 Wifi Router and I am able to access internet from this PC without issues. However I prefer using wired ethernet, so I connected the router with the PC, through a 5-port mini ethernet switch. When I did this, with the WiFi-dongle connected, the WiFi connection got suppressed and the Wired connection worked well.

Assuming that I do not need the WiFi dongle anymore, I removed it. My WiFi-Router is configured to limit WLAN TX-speed to 6Mbps and anykind of speed-test shows that indeed the bandwidth is effectively capped at 6Mbps. However I confirmed via speedtest, when connected over Wired-ethernet (but with the WiFi dongle still plugged-in), I could achieve around 20Mbps (which is usual for my broadband plan). However, **after removing the WiFi-dongle, the Wired ethernet stopped working**. This means that the router and internet have become inaccessible.

Here are the trouble-shooting & investigation steps I attempted:

- At this point, I attempted to ping & traceroute to the WiFi-Router, but it failed.
- Also, I changed from using DHCP assigned IP-address to the Wired interface, to using static-IP (outside the DHCP range). It didn't help.
- The ethernet-switch in-between the router and my desktop shows that the PHY-level connection is established.
- `ifconfig` shows the interface on my PC to be UP, and with IP-address assigned.
- `route` shows that the the default route to the Router is setup correctly as the Gateway.
- Restarting the PC, the switch, the router -- nothing changed the status, i.e. the PC is still unable to ping or traceroute the Router IP-address.

What else could I check to trouble-shoot this connectivity issue ?

Here's a graphical explanation of the situation, in 3 stages. Stage-3 doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the ip range your router is using? And is the ip you are using in that range? Some isp routers don't allow anything else than the ip range dhcp on the router is giving out.

Comment: Yes, the IP address ranges are correct. Both wired and wireless LAN are assigned IP from the private 192.168.2.x class space (/24 subset), and I use a combination of DHCP Mac-id -> IP reservation (in the static IP range), and DHCP that is assigned by the router as DHCP server. I am 100% sure there are no conflicts around that.